# Floating window Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I'm developing an application with Cordova, and need to display some information brought from BD when the user clicks a button, however I can not send to another screen, I would like to display a kind of popup, there how to do this?
Obs .: I've tried to use Toast but it is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

@Vinicius,

What is BD?

To do the thing you want use  with position:absolute.
These are the classes you want.

```
.hidden  {visibility:hidden;display:none;}
.visible {visibility:visible;display:block;}
```

And you will need to layer it on top of everything

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Questions?

Comment: Added a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jessemonroy650/3345e01a439ddb4e11e1) you can [try at codepen.io](http://codepen.io/jessemonroy650/full/ZGXBgV)